# How to draw fractional power functions with Tikz in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw function .... with the LaTeX package but I can't. I draw the function in GeoGebra but it does not run in LaTeX.
Please guide.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-9.620000000000001,
xmax=9.620000000000001,
ymin=-8.65,
ymax=4.09,
xtick={-9,-8,...,9},
ytick={-8,-7,...,4},]
\clip(-9.62,-8.65) rectangle (9.62,4.09);
\draw[line width=2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-9.620000000000001:9.620000000000001] plot(\x,{(\x)^(2/3)});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (-8,4) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please turn your code fragent into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding teh documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages. Regarding: "it does not run": do you get any error message?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-9.620000000000001,
xmax=9.620000000000001,
ymin=-8.65,
ymax=4.09,
xtick={-9,-8,...,9},
ytick={-8,-7,...,4}]
\addplot[domain=-9.62:9.62,smooth,samples=71] {sign(x)*(abs(x))^(2/3)};
\path (-8,4) node {$\scriptstyle f$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the exponent "2/3" is being calculated as a (binary) decimal expansion that does not actually equal 2/3.  The function "x<sup>2/3</sup>" is mathematically equivalent to both "(x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>(1/3)</sup>" and to "(x<sup>(1/3)</sup>)<sup>2</sup>", but the latter does not work in finite-precision calculation over the reals, failing for negative x.  Similar to what @schrödingers-cat suggests in his comment, you have to manually tell TiKz to calculate "(\x*\x)^(1/3)".

(Note that whenever you write "x^y" with non-integer y, the calculation engine in TiKz will actually evaluate "e^(y*log(x))", and will always fail for negative x.)